I Have error "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list'"
When i update table, laravel is broken
On another site same code work well

                        $flatBuilder = Lot::where('lotid', $lotid);
                        $arFlat = $flatBuilder->first();

                        $arFields[] = array(
                            'lotid' => $lotid,
                            'lot' => $lot,
                            'type' => $type,
                            'status' => $status,
                            'price' => $price,
                            'pricesq' => $pricesq,
                            'area' => $area,
                            'floor' => $floor,
                            'height' => $height
                        );

                        if ($arFlat) {
                            $flatBuilder->update($arFields);
                        } else {
                            Lot::create($arFields);
                        }

update dont work...
Where is my mistake?
Need help!

The problem is here $arFields[]. Try like this $arFields['lotid'] = $lotid, In this way make your array $arFields structure and  then check. I hope it will resolve the issue.

Since you're already assigning array value to the $arFields, you don't need to initialize it as empty array. Change your code to this (remove [] from $$arFields)
$arFields = array(
    'lotid' => $lotid,
    'lot' => $lot,
    'type' => $type,
    'status' => $status,
    'price' => $price,
    'pricesq' => $pricesq,
    'area' => $area,
    'floor' => $floor,
    'height' => $height
);

Result:
array:9 [
  "lotid" => 1
  "lot" => 1
  "type" => 1
  "status" => 1
  "price" => 1
  "pricesq" => 1
  "area" => 1
  "floor" => 1
  "height" => 1
]

The way you wrote it, your array has one element, which has a value of array:
array:1 [
  0 => array:9 [
    "lotid" => 1
    "lot" => 1
    "type" => 1
    "status" => 1
    "price" => 1
    "pricesq" => 1
    "area" => 1
    "floor" => 1
    "height" => 1
  ]
]

And $flatBuilder->update($arFields) is using that element (0 in this case), to find the relevant column.
